# Appropriately iterating through read.dbf with a loop

Tags: r, dbf

My attempt to iterate through all ".dbfs" located in a folder in order to perform "read.dbf" has failed.

The code is below:

```
files <- list.files(path="\\\\CLOVER\\Projects\\TDEP_Compare\\Tasks\\06_StatsTables\\DBFs\\", pattern="*.dbf", all.files=F, full.names=T)
files
for (i in files){
#
  print(i) 
  data <- read.dbf(i, as.is = true)
  head(data, n=10)
  names(data)
}
```

The result in the console is as follows:

```
> for (i in files){
+   print(i) 
+   data <- read.dbf(i, as.is = true)
+   head(data, n=10)
+   names(data)
+ }
[1] "\\\\CLOVER\\Projects\\TDEP_Compare\\Tasks\\06_StatsTables\\DBFs\\CMAQ_n_td_2002_frst_pts_Int.dbf"
Error in read.dbf(i, as.is = true) : object 'true' not found
>
```

Any thoughts on the syntax of read.dbf and how I could properly parse i through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `true` in capitals like
`data <- read.dbf(i, as.is = TRUE)`

Reason: `true` is a function in R... See `?true`
but you mean the value `TRUE`